# Swap first and second item from json array?

Tags: arrays, json, shell, unix, jq

Suppose I have an array : `["1","2","3"]`. How can I swap the first element `1` with the later one which is `2` ?

That is the end result to be `["2","1","3"]`

Answer (score 1):

As `jq` is tagged, how about the `reverse` function applied to the sublist containing the first two elements

```sh
jq '.[:2] |= reverse'
```

```json
["2","1","3"]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/-PeuwWsybN)

Comment: How would this be if I want to swap the last two items?

Comment: @Missu, `.[-2:]`

Answer (score 0):

More generically, if more prosaically:

```
def swap(i;j): .[i] as $t | .[i]=.[j]|.[j]=$t; 
swap(0;1)
```